# iOS Detect IPv6 Support

Tags: ios, c, ipv6

I have an iOS application that utilizes a library with built in socket control (in other words, I don't create the sockets myself, I just pass the library the parameters for the sockets). I have two API's available to me from the library, each containing a configurable address that is either IPv4 or IPv6. Then there is a toggle I can configure to tell the library whether it should use IPv6 or IPv4.

**Here is an example of how the configuration is loaded**

```
// IPv6 Configuration
char* ipv6_addr = . . .; // This is defined elsewhere
config.server.s6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
config.server.s6.sin6_port   = htons(1122);
inet_pton(AF_INET6, ipv6_addr, &(config.server.s6.sin6_addr));

// IPv4 Configuration
char* ipv4_addr = . . .; // This is defined elsewhere
config.server.s4.sin_family = AF_INET;
config.server.s4.sin_port   = htons(1122);
inet_pton(AF_INET, ipv4_addr, &(config.server.s4.sin_addr));

config.use_ipv6 = 1; // Set to 0 to use IPv4
```

I can currently successfully connect to either IPv4 or IPv6 depending on what the device and client network (ISP, etc) support, but I have to configure the use_ipv6 flag manually.

**What I need to do is check if the client's network (ISP, etc) supports IPv6. If so, use an IPv6 connection. But if not, use an IPv4 connection. Preferably something like this: `config.use_ipv6 = has_ipv6_support();` in which the function `has_ipv6_support()` returns either a `1` or `0`.**

So, how do I go about checking if the network has IPv6 support?

> Notes
>
> a) I can't use the regular methods of `getaddrinfo` since the sockets are handled inside of the library and I cannot use hostnames due to  my infrastructure base shifting IP's around a lot. I only have either an IPv4 address or an IPv6 address at my disposal.
>
> b) This is written in C, but I wouldn't mind a solution in Objective C either.
>
> c) It would be difficult to simply test an IPv6 connection to decide since I'm using UDP for the connection and would have to timeout on a response. That's a bit more logic than I'd like to be involved as this will need to be done every now and again and I don't want to kill the battery by keeping the network adapters alive. I'd prefer to be able to pull this information locally.

Comment: Usually the best answer is "just try to use IPv6, and if that doesn't work fall back fast to IPv4". Is that an option? Also remember that your app needs to work from behind a NAT64 gateway, so you'll still need to resolve IPv4 address to NAT64 IPv6 addresses in some situations.

Comment: @SanderSteffann Since the application uses UDP protocol, it's difficult to test a connection without a timeout on the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a UDP server, your library should listen both to IPv4 and IPv6 addresses simultaneously. Because there is strictly no mean to know which of IPv4 and IPv6 is available, without doing regular attempts to connect to a remote host with IPv4 and IPv6. This is because a network failure can occur in the network, somewhere on the IPv6 or IPv4 path only, to the remote sides that may talk to your app. So, either change your library (but it does not seem possible), or change your batteries regularly! Sorry :-(